# Convert a csv to excel file with file paths

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this :

```
Attribute_1_0, Attribute_2_0, file_Path_0
Attribute_1_1, Attribute_2_1, file_Path_1
```

But I would like to convert it to an xls file and translate the file paths to links in the Excel file, so that the user can interact directly with those files.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Create a macro that can open a file, extract each item in the csv file and put it in the correct cell. Loop until complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can directly convert paths to hyperlink.
Either automatically, either by using a macro "=HYPERLINK(CELL)" and looping it.